# MQ - Handling of messages exceeding max length moving to dead queue

Tags: ibm-mq

This is a general question. Let me say I have a queue manager locally. I have a transmission queue/remote queue definition setup through which I connect to destination queue manager queue. If destination queue manager queue's maximum message length capacity is 1000 and if I put a message length more than that it automatically moves to destination queue manager dead letter queue provided that my transmission queue max message length is more than what I input. This is the expected behaviour. But is there any way on MQ world to handle this and not move it to dead queue? Or is it the sole responsibility of the application that puts this message to not put over the max length?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only time I have seen the MAXMSGL of a queue set to a lower value than the default 4MB is on a z/OS (Mainframe) queue manager, and this is usually set to the record size that a COBOL program is expecting to read.  I think one could ague it would be better for the app to read the message and move it to it's own "bad message" queue if the length is greater than what the app can handle rather than do it at the MQ level but many times these COBOL programs are very old and do not have anyone that has time to maintain them.

Comment: Because the programs can't be changed or no one is willing to change them it becomes better to do it at the MQ level to allow those messages to go to the DLQ and not stop the app from processing properly sized messages.

Comment: To answer your question with a quick comment, if you want to ensure from the MQ configuration that the app putting to the QREMOTE can't put a message that is larger than 1000 bytes, you could set `MAXMSGL(1000)` on the `XMITQ` itself.  This would only be viable if the `XMITQ` is not shared with other `QREMOTE` object that need to put messages larger than `1000` bytes.

Comment: Another option if the app putting is a client connection you could set  `MAXMSGL(1000)` on the `SVRCONN` channel, again this would only work if the only messages the app(s) using that channel put are not greater than 1000 bytes.  You also may have to put some extra room for the `MQMD` so test any of these options to make sure they work properly.

Comment: You can configure the receiver channel at the destination to not put it to the DLQ. Look up the USEDLQ parameter on the channel. This would however mean that for persistent message the channel would stop, which is not an improvement. Non-persistent messages would be thrown away. What alternative behaviour were you hoping for btw?

Comment: Thanks Morag Hughson. I think you have given me something to explore. My expectation is in a real time environment, the receiver end queue manager/application should not end up doing some remediation for a mistake by the sender. But still we will end up having receiver channel going down which is no good.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default Maximum Message Length (i.e. MAXMSGL) from 4MB to a small value is a bad idea.

Myth: MQ does **NOT** allocate space based on the value in maximum message length field.  Setting it to a very small value or to a very large value has not bearing on the disk space.  MQ ONLY writes the size/amount of the real message.

Secondly, the application team should tell the MQAdmin what the largest message will be that the application will send.  If they say 10MB then the MQAdmin can increase max. message length to 10MB or something a little larger i.e. 12MB.

The largest value that can be used is 100MB.

Note: The MQAdmin will need to increase the max. message length for: channel, XMITQ, local queue and the dead letter queue for any message larger than the default size of 4MB or it will not flow.

Comment: Don't forget the `QMGR` itself needs to be updated.  Also between queue managers both "sending side" and "receiving side" channels need to be updated as well as any `SVRCONN` channels used by the apps to PUT or GET the larger messages.  If it is a client connection to a `SVRCONN`, how you increase the client side `MAXMSGL` depends on the API and version of MQ in some cases and how you specify connection details.

Comment: If the connection is client-to-QMgr (SVRCONN) then the application will receive 1 of many reason codes rather than have the message go to the dead letter queue (DLQ).  i.e. MQRC_MSG_TOO_BIG_FOR_Q, MQRC_MSG_TOO_BIG_FOR_CHANNEL, etc..

Comment: Roger, I agree with you, I was just adding some addition information to your last Note for what the MQAdmin would need to increase to allow for messages larger than 4MB.  ex `MAXMSGL` needs to be increased for each of the following: `CCDT CLNTCONN (or equivalent setting appropriate to API used) > QMGR (where PUT happens)  > SVRCONN > XMITQ > SDR (or equivalent) -> RCVR (or equivalent) > QMGR (where GET happens) > QLOCAL > SVRCONN > CCDT CLNTCONN (or equivalent setting appropriate to API used)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Roger and JoshMc. Infact I tried both options, client to QM and between QM and QM. Client to QM is fine as the client receives the error code and basically nothing happens. But the concern is only between sender QM and receiver QM. What I have seen mostly is that there will be only one transmission queue with maximum message length to connect to a particular queue manager. All the different remote connection/queues use that transmission queue. So if the sender commits a mistake by sending a large message than the destination queue cannot accept, it usually end up passing through the transmission queue but failing in destination and reaching the destination's dead queue. Now the destination owner is alerted/or need to take some remediation for a mistake that he didn't commit. That's the whole reason for me asking this question. Thanks a lot for you both on shedding more light and spending your time for me.

I think Morag Hughson has given out something for me to try out but still it will have its own negative impact. But I was looking for something like that where we can control at the MQ level to not allow the message to go to destination dead queue.

Comment: If the client can't send to the QM then you shouldn't need to worry about sender QM to receiver QM.  While you said that there will be only one XMITQ, you can always define different CHLs with XMITQs for different  MAXMSGLs.  This may be ok if there are only a few different sizes.

Comment: Yes JoshMc that would be a good solution. But as you said, as long as the communication doesn't get complex with more different needs. Else we will end up consuming lot of resources. From all the discussions and view points in this topic, it's seems the solution is a narrow path with lot of trade offs. Thanks, I now have some knowledge compared to when I have posted the question.